# Overloading new for a class

Tags: c++, memory-management

I can declare in the header file for MyClass something like:

```
void* operator new(size_t size) throw(bad_alloc);
```

and in the MyClass source file define:

```
void* MyClass::operator new(size_t size) throw(bad_alloc)
{
    cout << "overloading new" << endl;
    return (::operator new(size));
}
```

and to use this:

```
MyClass *m = new MyClass();
```

So my question is- in the above line of code where we use the overloaded new operator- I cannot see us passing the size argument of type size_t to the overloaded new operator?? Yet in the definition for the overloaded new operator it requires it?

Comment: For information regarding the various forms and requirements of dynamic memory management in C++, I suggest reviewing **"C++11 § 18.6 Dynamic memory management"**. It is the main part of the standard that, though far too lengthy to detail here, covers essentially all your questions asked. Section **"C++11 § 5.3.4 New"** covers the `new` operator expression in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**
The size is infered from the compiler depending on the size of the object which is created with the new operator.

**Example**

```
struct Example {
    int X;
    int Y;
}

Example *A = new Example();
```

would call the new operator/function with the parameter size equal to 8 (16 on x64 systems), it can also be more or less depending on alignment.

The new call would be translated from the compiler as follows (if no exceptions were used in the constructor and if the compiler decides to optimize away the catching of the not needed catch block):

```
Example *A = (Example*)Example::new(sizeof(Example));
A->A(); // call constructor
```

Comment: And, in order to (hopefully) prevent even more *"Why isn't the size of my class X"* questions in the future, alignment may also take place, adding to the size of an instance.

Comment: There is one little detail in your answer that's wrong: In the last line, you call `Example::new` which then calls `::operator new` but in no place is there a constructor call! I'd split that in two lines, one where you get a void pointer and a second where you call placement new. If you now add exception safety it gets another few lines before you are at the actual equivalent.